# finding the position of a fraction in farey sequence

Tags: algorithm, math

For finding the position of a fraction in [farey sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence), i tried to implement the algorithm given here http://www.math.harvard.edu/~corina/publications/farey.pdf  under "***initial algorithm***" but i can't understand where i'm going wrong, i am not getting the correct answers . Could someone please point out my mistake.
eg. for order n = 7 and fractions 1/7 ,1/6 i get same answers.
Here's what i've tried for given degree(n), and a fraction a/b:

```
sum=0;
int A[100000];
A[1]=a;

for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
  A[i]=i*a-a;

for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
{
  for(j=i+i;j<=n;j+=i)
    A[j]-=A[i];
}

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  sum+=A[i];

ans = sum/b;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm doesn't use any particular properties of a and b. In the first part, every relevant entry of the array A is a multiple of a, but the factor is independent of a, b and n. Setting up the array ignoring the factor a, i.e. starting with A[1] = 1, A[i] = i-1 for 2 <= i <= n, after the nested loops, the array contains the [totients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), i.e. A[i] = phi(i), no matter what a, b, n are. The sum of the totients from 1 to n is the number of elements of the Farey sequence of order n (plus or minus 1, depending on which of 0/1 and 1/1 are included in the definition you use). So your answer is always the approximation (a*number of terms)/b, which is close but not exact.

I've not yet looked at how yours relates to the algorithm in the paper, check back for updates later.

Addendum: Finally had time to look at the paper. Your initialisation is not what they give. In their algorithm, `A[q]` is initialised to `floor(x*q)`, for a rational `x = a/b`, the correct initialisation is

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
    A[i] = (a*i)/b;
}
```

in the remainder of your code, only `ans = sum/b;` has to be changed to `ans = sum;`.

Answer (score 2):

A non-algorithmic way of finding the position *t* of a fraction in the Farey sequence of order *n*>1 is shown in Remark 7.10(ii)(a) of the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411026), under *m:=n*-1, where mu-bar stands for the number-theoretic Mobius function on positive integers taking values from the set {-1,0,1}.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Java solution that works. Add head(0/1), tail(1/1) nodes to a SLL.
Then start by passing headNode,tailNode and setting required orderLevel.

```
public void generateSequence(Node leftNode, Node rightNode){        
    Fraction left = (Fraction) leftNode.getData();
    Fraction right= (Fraction) rightNode.getData();
    FractionNode midNode = null;
    int midNum = left.getNum()+ right.getNum();
    int midDenom = left.getDenom()+ right.getDenom();
    if((midDenom <=getMaxLevel())){
        Fraction middle = new Fraction(midNum,midDenom);
        midNode = new FractionNode(middle);
    }
    if(midNode!= null){
        leftNode.setNext(midNode);
        midNode.setNext(rightNode);
        generateSequence(leftNode, midNode);
        count++;
    }else if(rightNode.next()!=null){
        generateSequence(rightNode, rightNode.next());
    }

}
```